# How to handle events in folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

How to add a line between two markers when one marker is clicked. For example, in the below code, I am creating two markers, for Bangalore and Delhi. Suppose when I click Bangalore, a line should be drawn from Bangalore to Delhi. How to get this done in folium?

```
import folium as fl

bangalore = [12.9716, 77.5946]
delhi = [28.7041, 77.1025]
m = fl.Map(location = delhi, zoom_start = 4)
fl.CircleMarker(location = bangalore, tooltip = 'Bangalore',radius = 2, fill = True).add_to(m)
fl.CircleMarker(location = delhi, tooltip = 'New Delhi',radius = 2, fill = True).add_to(m)
m.save('map.html')
```